# Putting arguments for my crawler in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a scrapy crawler but I need to add the ability to read some arguments from the command line and then populates some static fields in my spider class. I also need to override the initialiser so it populates some of the spider fields.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
import re


class TutsplusItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "tutsplus"
    allowed_domains = ["bbc.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        # We stored already crawled links in this list
        crawledLinks = []

        for link in links:
            # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
            # if linkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
            if not link in crawledLinks:
                link = "http://www.bbc.com" + link
                crawledLinks.append(link)
                yield Request(link, self.parse)

        titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "media__link")]/text()').extract()
        for title in titles:
            item = TutsplusItem()
            item["title"] = title
            print("Title is : %s" % title)
            yield item
```

Then it should be run as:

```
scrapy runspider crawler.py arg1 arg2
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by overriding the init method of your spider like this.

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "tutsplus"
    allowed_domains = ["bbc.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.com/"]
    arg1 = None
    arg2 = None

    def __init__(self,  arg1, arg2,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        # We stored already crawled links in this list
        crawledLinks = []

        for link in links:
            # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
            # if linkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
            if not link in crawledLinks:
                link = "http://www.bbc.com" + link
                crawledLinks.append(link)
                yield Request(link, self.parse)

        titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "media__link")]/text()').extract()
        for title in titles:
            item = TutsplusItem()
            item["title"] = title
            print("Title is : %s" % title)
            yield item
```

Then run your spider like

```
scrapy crawl tutsplus -a arg1=arg1 -a arg2=arg2
```

Comment: thanks for the response but what if I want to run like "scrapy runspider Crawler.py arg1 arg2", for example using "getopt.getopt(args, options, [long_options])"

Comment: You will have to dig deeper into class implementation of runspider commands implementation.